# Watson visual recognition API update

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

It seems to be no more possible to associate public IMages of IBM Cloud Object Storage with Watson visual recognition. something has been changed in the type of calls between the 2 services. 
My code below use to work but know it says there is no "images founds" .

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from os import environ
import sys
import os 
import boto3
import pprint
from boto3 import client
from botocore.utils import fix_s3_host
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3


param_1= "MY S3 KEY"
param_2= "MY S3 SECRET KEY "
param_3= "https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net"  
param_4= "MY BUCKET "
param_5= "MY WATSON API KEY "

#The Name of my image I want to analyse that is currently in my bucket and is made public
objectNMAE='THIEF.jpg'

s3ressource = client(
    service_name='s3', 
    endpoint_url= param_3,
    aws_access_key_id= param_1,
    aws_secret_access_key=param_2,
    use_ssl=True,
    )
visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3('2016-05-20', api_key=param_5)

#The URL of my image I made public with Public ACL
urltobeanalysed="%s/%s/%s" % (param_3,param_4,objectNMAE)   

#For Debug, I use an image that can be viewed in a web-browser
URL2="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama#/media/File:President_Barack_Obama.jpg"

print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.classify(images_url=urltobeanalysed), indent=2))
```

What is more, the image that is made public used to be displayed in my browser, now when I enter the URL, it is downloading instead..  Any Clues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research in SO, it seems that IBM COS is aligned with AWS S3 behavior, they changed some thing in object header behavior.
I had to specify the content type to be image/jpeg: 
'contentType' => 'image/jpeg'

otherwhise nothing was displayed. No it works.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the image you provide in the code is the URL of wiki **page** displaying a big image. The direct link to the image, that you should provide in the API call is [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg/1280px-President_Barack_Obama.jpg). (Try right-clicking the image in your browser, and doing something like "Copy image location", depends on your browser).

Comment: Thanks, I Upvoted your answer, but this is only part of the reason. I would like to ear from IBM BlueMix COS team what they did regarding the content type operation. This changed my app and had to add few lines of code to update. I would like to have an update when the APi is updated and clear details of the update. Thanks.